# Setting up LAMP Web Server on AWS EC2 t1 Micro

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, lamp

I'm sorry for being dumb, but I am really stuck for few days. This is my first time using AWS. I have successfully installed LAMP web server under t1.micro on my customer's AWS account `http://54.72.132.215/` following [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) . But I don't know what to do next after the installation. My goal is:

1. Setup a Domain
2. Run a Prestashop.

I hope you can guide me to the right path, I am totally lost. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a domain with someone, this is outside of Amazon. Just google domain name registrars:

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=domain%20name%20registrar

Then you'll need to point your domain to your Amazon EC2 instance. I would suggest using Route 53 to do this, another Amazon AWS service that makes it easier to setup and control your domains:

http://aws.amazon.com/route53/

Once you have that setup, visiting your name domain should show the default apache *It works!* page, if you've correctly setup  your LAMP server. It'll look something like these:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=default+apache+web+page&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=yRfWU_v8OeHe7Abp1ICICw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1457&bih=881#imgdii=_

You'll want to add a new **vhost** for your new PrestaShop site, this will allow you to setup a specific set of files to serve for your new URL, and means you can add other sites to the server later on. Just a quick google shows multiple tutorials on doing this, here's one of them:

http://calebogden.com/multiple-websites-amazon-ec2-linux-virtual-hosts/

Then follow the tutorial in the PrestaShop documentation about installing PrestaShop via the command line:

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Installing+PrestaShop+using+the+command-line+script

Now I'm guessing that all those steps in one go is a little overwhelming, so I would suggest you break this task down into chunks and work on them one at a time, and post a few different questions on *StackOverflow* and probably **ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/**, as that is better suited to setting up servers.

To summarise you need to:

- register a domain name and point it to your EC2 server, you should see the default apache page
- create a new vhost to server web pages for your new domain
- follow the guide on PrestaShop about installing the software

Treat each of those a separate task. This question covers lots of topics in one very general idea, the full answer to your problem wouldn't really fit in a single post.

ServerFault will probably have a lot of your answers already, regarding setting up domains and vhosts at least.

Comment: Thanks @willshaw I appreciate your quick response. I will try that. Thanks

Comment: Hi I am now setting up the vhost, when I ran this command

`# /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

I always get this error

`bash: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Permission denied`

Comment: I tried connecting via filezilla as `ec2-user` but I can't see any 
directory like `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`. It's pretty weird for me because look like I successfully installed the apache2 http://www.kabestany.com.pl/